# How to Reassign Function Parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I understand that it can be bad to [reassign function parameters](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) but I don't quite see how it would be done in this case? I'm using a forEach loop to cycle through the todo list array (which is on an object) `todos` and alter the `completed` property and I don't see how I can not reuse `eachTodo`

How would this be rewritten so that it has the same functionality but doesn't reuse `eachTodo`?

```
    this.todos.forEach((eachTodo) => {
      if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
        eachTodo.completed = false;
      } else {
        eachTodo.completed = true;
      }
    });
```

Full project [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/false-aquarius?path=public/client.js:34:4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not reassigning parameters here. If you were reassigning them, there would be some line with `eachTodo =` in it - but that's not the case here. Rather, you're *mutating* the `eachTodo` parameter.

If you want to avoid mutating the parameter as well, one option would be to use `.map` to create a *copy* of each `eachTodo`, and then reassign `this.todos` outside of the `forEach` call:

```
this.todos = this.todos.map((eachTodo) => {
  if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
    return { ...eachTodo, completed: false };
  } else {
    return { ...eachTodo, completed: true };
  }
});
```

(make sure there are no other references to individual `todo`s to avoid memory leaks)

Comment: I got it, eslint was warning me about a reassigned function parameter so hence the question! I see now that it was in fact referencing the _mutation_ - I'm just learning `.map` now so will implement

Comment: Could you add a little explanation about the memory leaks you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't assign to `eachTodo`, so I don't see how the link to the discussion about reassigning parameters is relevant.

What do you mean by "reuse `eachTodo`"? If you mean you want code that mentions the variable name less often, here's one way:

```
  if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
    eachTodo.completed = false;
  } else {
    eachTodo.completed = true;
  }
```

can be reduced (by pulling out the common `eachTodo.completed =` part) to:

```
eachTodo.completed = completedTodos === totalTodos ? false : true;
```

This line can be simplified further (as a general rule, whenever you have a `?:` operator where one of the branches is just `true` or `false`, it can be simplified):

```
eachTodo.completed = completedTodos !== totalTodos;
```